# Android emulator crashes after about 2 hours with clojurescript, react-native, re-natal

Tags: android, react-native, clojurescript

Developing Android app with re-natal: my stack has ClojureScript, reagent, re-frame, and React Native.  In general it is working well, but the Android emulator (Nexus_5X_API_25_x86) crashes after a couple of hours.  In the Android Monitor window of Android Studio the message is "... W/unknown:React: Calling JS function after bridge has been destroyed" and the status shows as "DISCONNECTED".  My web search for "re-natal emulator crash" did not turn up much.

I'm told that the emulator has a tendency to crash, but the rate seems a little high.  Is this rate typical, or should I be worried about these crashes?  Is anybody else with a setup like mine experiencing similar problems?